# Equalizing lines of data according to DateTime

Tags: c#, database, text-files

This is similar to another question I've asked here on SO, but it's different enough from it that I haven't been able to come up with an answer for it on my own yet.  I think the best way to introduce my problem is with a picture:

[image: example]

I have several text files (4 in this example), each with millions of lines of data in the following format:

```
TIME DATA

File #1
104500 4098
104501 34098
104502 1321
104502 3408
104503 4587
104503 1204
104503 49858
104504 1029
104505 4058
104506 7576

File #2
104500 23408
104500 2131
104501 5686
104502 6839
104502 21838
104503 86760
104503 20812
104503 85719
104504 4877
104505 2220
104506 4847

File #3
104500 23042
104501 12391
104501 5857
104501 6979
104502 2196
104502 21039
104503 9263
104503 50573
104503 18361
104504 17545
104505 67612
104506 21075

File #4
104500 1193
104501 8664
104502 1028
104502 68561
104503 69178
104503 1230
104503 12048
104504 8843
104505 9910
104506 53978
104506 13722
```

The problem is that a given time in one file may have more or less data entries than it has in another file.  In the picture above for example, there is only one entry for 10:45:00 in File #1, but there are two entries for 10:45:00 in File #2.  I'm hoping to get each file to have the same amount of lines per time entry, so in my example with Files #1 and #2, a 'filler' line would be added after the the first '104500 4098' line, and this filler line would just be an exact copy of the line above it (104500 4098 in this case).  Ideally these 'filler' lines would be inserted into the text files being read from, and not written to a new text file.

What I've come up with so far is that I need to:

--count the number of lines for each given time

--find which file has the highest number of lines for each given time

--insert the 'filler' line(s) in each file where necessary

Unfortunately I don't really know how to do any of that.  I have some ideas, but they're all vague at this point so I don't really know what I should read up on yet.  The only real code that I've come up with so far is that I can assign all files in the directory to an array using Directory.GetFiles, and I can then loop through all the files that way, but that doesn't get me very far.

These lines of data are generated by a program, which then writes the lines to text files.  I don't have access to the code which generates the lines of data.

If anyone has any ideas as to how I might accomplish this, a hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why does there need to be a filler line in the first place? If each file may or may not have a timestamp, why not just ignore the null time?

Comment: I don't think that would work, because eventually I'd like to perform calculations on the sum of all data for each given time entry across all files in the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us distill this situation down to only two time stamps and I will provide the answer.

Below I have recreated three files. Each of the file *buffers* have timestamps of 104500 and 104501, while the 2nd file has two 501s as expressed as the problem which is being addressed. That means that file1 and file3 only have one 501. Then I simulate the parsing the data from the files and *project* them into a class holder which has a file ID, the data and the timestamp. Once all data is acquired for each file buffer, I union the data. With the data in one IEnumerable list I then grouped by time; *this is key to the eventual processing, the grouping*.

Now all you have to do is extract the unit of time that is of interest and do the calculations on that set, keeping in mind the missing data for file1 and file3. You could then manipulate the grouped result to either add more timestamps for the missing or just pop off the last value.

Answer: **Regardless, don't work within a file, put the data in memory and adjust to the missing data when you do the calculation.**

Here is what the data looks like, see how it is convently grouped (the key) by times of 104500 an 104501. One justs extracts the target time from that grouping with all the values from file 1 - 3 and does the calcuation.

[image]

Here is the code to get it organized (the dump method is from Linqpad which shows the data, which I showed in the picture)

```
void Main()
{
    string File1 = @"104500 1 
104501 1 
";

    string File2 = 
@"104500 2 
104501 2
104501 4
"; 

    string File3 = 
@"104500 5 
104501 5
"; 

    var ds3 = ExtractData(File1, 1).Union( ExtractData(File2, 2) )
                                   .Union( ExtractData(File3, 3))
                                   .GroupBy (d => d.Time );
    ds3.Dump();


}

public static IEnumerable<DataAndTime> ExtractData(string data, int fileID)
{

    string pattern = @"^(?<Time>[^\s]+)(?:\s+)(?<Data>[^\s]+)";

     return Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)
                   .OfType<Match>()
                   .Select (m => new DataAndTime()
                                   { 
                                     FileID = fileID,
                                     Time = m.Groups["Time"].Value,
                                     Data = int.Parse(m.Groups["Data"].Value)
                                }
                                   );

}


// Define other methods and classes here

public class DataAndTime
{
   public int FileID { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public int Data { get; set; }
```

}

UPDATE: Extract at Timeslice

Below is code to extract an indexed value into a target time. I deem this a timeslice. When one asks for a timeslice, the code has to be smart enough to identify the last value as a default when the index (timeslice) asked for is out of the range.

For example the file 1 has one items, if I were to ask for a time slice index two it should retrieve the last value which is the first. If I ask for index 100 it should return that value as well.

So let us look at the time 104501 and get that data. Then we will group by the file ID

```
var ds3 = ExtractData(File1, 1).Union( ExtractData(File2, 2) )
                               .Union( ExtractData(File3, 3))
                               .GroupBy (d => d.Time )
                               .First (d => d.Key == "104501")
                               .GroupBy (d => d.FileID) ;
```

and our data looks like this for ds3:

[image: Data for 104501 time]

Now we need to create a method which will handle the extraction of a timeslice and handle missing index (slice) values. To do that I will use [DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) to specify that the last value of the file will be a default if we ask for too many. Here is that code

```
public static int ValueAtSnapshotSlice(int slice, IEnumerable<DataAndTime> data)
{
    var defaultData = data.Last();

    return data.Take(slice)
               .DefaultIfEmpty(defaultData)
               .Last().Data;

}
```

Then if we look at file 2 and ask for time slices 1, 2 and a 3 (even 4+) which does not exist we expect 2, 4, 4, 4 as resultant values. Here are the calls against ds3 above

```
ValueAtSnapshotSlice(1, ds3.First (d => d.Key == 2)); // 2
ValueAtSnapshotSlice(2, ds3.First (d => d.Key == 2)); // 4
ValueAtSnapshotSlice(3, ds3.First (d => d.Key == 2)); // 4
ValueAtSnapshotSlice(4, ds3.First (d => d.Key == 2)); // 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it's going to take me a while to figure out what everything in this code does, but I can see already that grouping by the timestamp is what I need to be doing.

Comment: "You could then manipulate the grouped result to either add more timestamps [...]" -- I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  I've been using foreach loops to go through each IGrouping and .Count() the size of each group, and I've even tried to group each IGrouping into smaller groups, but it's not working out.  So I'm wondering, should this be a relatively simple task, or a complex one?  My attempts at solutions are becoming more and more complex, and I'm thinking there may be something I'm overlooking.  Not looking for an answer, just a hint if possible.

Comment: Disregard my above comment, it turns out I had a fundamental misunderstanding of 'foreach', and now I think I've solved my problem.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @BrianSnow HAR! You are not getting off that easy. I have created a method which will extract the value, and if it is does not exist as found in your data, it defaults to the last for that time. This is an excellent linq learning experiance for you. Note I no longer think in for loops but in linq IEnumerables and extensions to manipuate data...if you continue with linq you will too. Regardless see the new update in the code.

Comment: @ OmegaMan  Thanks so much!  I've read over your edit a couple times, and I'm going to call it a night tonight because my brain is kind of shutting down.  But I'm going to read over it again tomorrow and figure out exactly how the new code you posted functions.  Thanks again for the time you've spent on this.

Comment: @BrianSnow it was an answer which married my two favorite technologies, regex and linq. I like both of them because when one becomes proficient in them, its amazing what can be accomplished when used. Code is an art and properly crafted code working in conjunction is a thing of beauty. Glad to of helped.

Comment: Almost a year has passed, and LINQ is now my favorite feature of C#.  Thanks for introducing me to LINQ!

Comment: What? My goal was for regex to be your fav technology. ;-) Once one programs in linq there is no going back.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be simple.  For starters, you can't just insert a line in a text file.  You need to copy the file to a new file, inserting the line required in the process.  You can then delete the old file and rename the new file to take its place.

I'm assuming, too, that you don't know which file will need lines added before you process them all.  This means that you either need to load all the files into memory, process them there, and write out the result, or open a stream on each file plus a new file for each, and process the data from the old stream to the new stream for each file, inserting lines as required.

Comment: "I'm assuming, too, that you don't know which file will need lines added before you process them all." -- This is correct.  I was thinking along the lines of opening a stream for each file instead of loading them all into memory, because these files are quite large.  Thanks for your input.